# Stripe token - why isn't data-amount included in the token

Tags: stripe-payments

I've been playing with stripe recently and while i fully understand that the token hides the clients credit card details from the server. This [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe--pre-80957) suggests that the server should not rely on the data-amount since it can be changed by the client

```
Don’t Rely on the Form’s Price
A frequent mistake stems from using form data to contain the price of 
the product being purchased, possibly via a hidden input. Because a 
user can easily edit this input’s value, it’s unwise to depend on it.
Always fetch the price of the product from the server-side. Never rely
on the form to tell you. A simple database query is the preferred option.
```

Can someone explain to be why stripe does not include the data-amount value as a parameter in the token generation? Is there not a potential for a server side code to change the agreed price and overcharge the client.

Comment: You can still send the price from the form, just do some server-side validation to make sure it is accurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The token is a placeholder of a pending charge, it does not know how much you are going to charge yet. Once you are ready to charge the card an api request will be sent to Stripe along with the token. The concern about the amount deals with relying on POST data from a form that can be manipulated by the customer.

Comment: Your 'pending charge' is a good analogy, i suppose i had it in my head that the token was really an extra commitment to pay x in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Its up to you to set the charge amount. For example a hotel could authorize $100 to spend the night but then at check out discover that you used the minibar and then charge $150. Or the auto calculated shipping is off so when you actually purchase the shipping its $5 less and you decide to charge $5 less than your auth.

What you should be doing is calculating the amount to charge the customer, save it via a shopping cart like function in your DB (or serverside somehow) sending the checkout form to the customer then using the previously calculated amount run the auth then the charge.

Form data can easily be changed by the end user. Just open the page and right click (in chrome) and click inspect element. You can then arbitrarily change form data. So if you were using that, the user could set the price to $.01 for your $1,000.00 product.

The propose of tokenization in the PCI world is to keep sensitive data off your servers. Otherwise you would collect the PCI data yourself then send the amount off to the processor along with the PCI data. By not ever having the sensitive data touch your systems you save a ton of money and headache in PCI compliance. See this 115 page document: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-1.pdf

Hope that helps, Please comment and I'll try to help further if it doesn't.

Comment: In the hotel scenario, i would see the business process having two tokens. One for the initial $100 room fee, and second related to the checkout process which looks to cover the extra $50 mini bar fees. For the shopping cart example, i'd the shopping cart to calculate the total price with deductions before the stripe token is generated.

Comment: The issue is that you may not know that there is a deduction until after the auth has happened. For example I had a problem where someone from the military ordered a (almost literately) ton of product to be sent to a base in Germany, but there was a mistake with the USPS cost estimate the system got from USPS. When the shipping label purchase when though it was way different because technically it would be shipped to a US address then fwd to Germany. So we changed the amount before the actual charge went though.

Comment: Another good example is restaurant charges. The card is auth'd for an amount. The receipt is taken back to customer a tip added and the amount changed on charge.  There are a lot of credit card processes out there that make use of the two step process. That is why you have pending and available on your online bank account info.

Comment: If that answers you question, would you mind marking it as so? I'd really appreciate it! 

Thanks!